# File Upload through Pinia store and the Nuxt 3 server api

Tags: forms, vuejs3, pinia, nuxt3

In Nuxt 3 I have a Pinia store to manage the state. One of the store actions handles file uploads and forwards them to a Nuxt 3 server/api. The server/api is responsible for uploading the file data to a Rest API endpoint. - The /service/api/upload console.log of the body will output something like this:

```
Go to upload file Rest API ------WebKitFormBoundaryxlynp2SjAmsIq3Nn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="myfilename.png"
Content-Type: image/png
....
------WebKitFormBoundaryxlynp2SjAmsIq3Nn--
```

Currently the Rest API does not receive anything.
It works using Postman with a form-data body and a key "file".

How do I transform the body in the server/api script so that it correctly sends form data to the Rest API?

The Vue/Nuxt part with the form puts the file data to the Pinia store:

```
<script setup>

const store = useStore();

const file = ref();

const onChange = (event) => {
  file.value = event.target.files[0];
};

const uploadFile = async () => {
  try {
    if (!file.value) return;

    const body = new FormData();
    body.append("file", file.value, file.value.name);
    store.form_data = body;
    store.uploadFile();
    alert("Uploaded");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    alert("Error");
  }
};
</script>
<template>
  <input
     type="file"
    accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,image/jpeg"
    @change="onChange"
/>   
  <button @click="uploadFile">Upload</button>
</template>
```

This is the Pinia store - it receives the form input and forwards it to the server/api:

```
// /stores/myupload.ts
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
 
export const useStore = defineStore("myupload", {
  state: () => {
    return {
      form_data: null,   
    };
  },
  actions: {
    async uploadFile() {
      console.log(`Go to forward data to /server/api: `, this.form_data);
      try {
        const url = `/api/upload`
        const  { data } = await useFetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
          body: this.form_data,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "mutlipart/form-data",
          }
        });
        console.log('success)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error: '+ error);
      }
    }
  },
  ...  
});
```

The server/api receives the form data from the store. See above for the console.log output. It forwards the body to the Rest API endpoint which returns a 500 error:

```
// /service/api/upload
try {
  
   const body = await readBody(event);
   console.log(
   `Go to upload file Rest API`,
        body
   );

   const results = await $fetch(
    `${config.public.myURL}/api/v1/myapiendpoint`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      body: body,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "mutlipart/form-data",
        'Accept': '*/*', 
        Authorization: `Bearer ${config.myBEARER}`,
      },
    }
  );
  console.log(`success`);
  return results;
      
} catch (error) {
   console.log("Fehler: " + error);
   throw createError({
     statusCode: 500,
     statusMessage: 'Error on File Upload'
   })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to some help on the Nuxt Discord channel there is the following solution.

In the store remove the `"Content-Type": "mutlipart/form-data` from the headers object of the useFetch:

```
// /stores/myupload.ts
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
 
export const useStore = defineStore("myupload", {
  state: () => {
    return {
      form_data: null,   
    };
  },
  actions: {
    async uploadFile() {
       console.log(`Go to forward data to /server/api: `, this.form_data);
      try {
        const url = `/api/upload`
        const  { data } = await useFetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
          body: this.form_data,
          headers: {
            // "Content-Type": "mutlipart/form-data", // DISABLE
          }
        });
        console.log('success)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error: '+ error);
      }
    }
  },
  ...  
});
```

In the /service/api use readFormData() and do recreate your on newFormData object like this:

```
// /service/api/upload
export default defineEventHandler(async (event: Event) => {
    const config = useRuntimeConfig();
    try {
  
      // HERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS:
      const formData = await readFormData(event);
      const file = formData.get('file');
      let newFormData = new FormData();
      const blob = new Blob([file], { type: file.type });
      newFormData.append('file', blob, file.name);
     
      const results = await $fetch(
        `${config.public.myURL}/api/v1/myapiendpoint`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: newFormData,
          headers: {
            // "Content-Type": "mutlipart/form-data", // DISABLE
            'Accept': '*/*', 
            Authorization: `Bearer ${config.myBEARER}`,
          },
        }
      );
       console.log(`success`);
  return results;
      
} catch (error) {
   console.log("Fehler: " + error);
   throw createError({
     statusCode: 500,
     statusMessage: 'Error on File Upload'
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you try using `readMultipartFormData` instead of `readBody` inside server/api?

If it doesn't help, what is the exact error logged inside the catch block?